# Error al usar JSON.parse

Tags: typescript

Estoy itentando extraer los datos del `sessionStorage` y convertirlos en un `JSON` para acceder a un campo ID y usarlo para peticiones de la API. Bueno, al usar la sintaxis que se recomienda obtengo un error del `JSON.parse` cuando le paso el valor que quiero convertir, el error dice:

> No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "string | null" al parámetro de tipo "string".
> El tipo 'null' no se puede asignar al tipo 'string'.

Este es mi código:

```js
console.log('storage');
let storage = sessionStorage.getItem("US_LOGIN"); // Esto si me trae la data del Storage en String
let storage2 = JSON.parse(storage); // Aquí tengo el error (Dentro del parse), no puedo hacer la conversión
console.log(storage2);
```

Comment: Agrega más código para ver donde está el error.

Comment: Puede que te esté llegando NULL o un formato incorrecto, hazle un log a `storage` y coméntanos que te devuelve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El mensaje de error indica que typescript cree que podrías estar intentando usar un valor nulo como parámetro de la función `JSON.parse()`. Es decir que `sessionStorage` podría no contener el elemento `"US_LOGIN"` y por lo tanto `.getItem()`  podría retornar `null`.

Para evitar el error en compilación, puedes decir a typescript, mediante el operador `!`, que tranquilo que seguro que en ejecución nunca será null

```
let storage2 = JSON.parse(storage!);
```

Aunque, para estar totalmente seguros de evitar el error en tiempo de ejecución, deberías proporcionar, mediante el operador `??`, un valor por defecto en caso que `storage` sea *nullish* . Por ejemplo,

```
let storage2 = JSON.parse(storage ?? '{}');
```

Comment: @Cris223511 por el error sera? desde cuando JS se queja de los tipos? o sera que estoy entendiendo mal?

Comment: Bueno entonces es la etiqueta incorrecta, en JS saldría otro error.